# Text as Hyperlink in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, url, uitextfield

I have a text label with the text set as Contact Us.. When user taps on this label it should launch safari to open the web page.My doubt is how to make Contact Us as hyperlink.Now I can't modify my code to include a UIWebView..Please help me guys..I am in final stages of my project..If possible please help me with sample code..thanks for all your time

Comment: Do you want a blue line below the text?so it looks like a hyperlink?

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way is to make the UILabel into a UIButton, style it (use Custom type to get rid of button look).  Then connect to an Action that opens safari.

The action should do this:

```
NSURL *url = [[[ NSURL alloc ] initWithString: @"http://www.example.com" ] autorelease];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Comment: I have a text and part of it should be hyperlink can I give a try with the above approach

Comment: If you want to keep it a UILabel, inherit a class from it, then use that in IB instead of UILabel and override the getTouches message to find out if they are clicking the link

Comment: Or you could put a transparent button over the text.  If it's on top, it gets the touch.

Comment: how would you do that on NSApplication? (XOS instead of iOS)

Answer (score 0):

for XOS use NSWorkspace instead:

```
- (IBAction)btnPressed:(id)sender {
   NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString: @"https://www.google.com"];
   [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:url];
}
```

Comment: This will not create text as hyperlink. your code will only open URL.