# How can I create a "hyperlink" with Swift?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, hyperlink, swift

I'm trying to make separate pieces of text `UILabel`s clickable. What I'm looking for is commonly known as a hyperlink in web development.

```html
<a href="//example.com">Link 1</a>
<a href="//example.com/example">Link 2</a>
<a href="//example.com/other_example">Link 3</a>
```

Each `a` tag is its own `UILabel`, and it would ideally open Safari to the specified `href` when the text between the tags is clicked.

I've found a bevy of resources on how to do this sort of thing in Objective-C, but they all seem unnecessarily complicated and don't translate well to Swift (they fit an Objective-C organizational structure that doesn't work well in Swift and goes against the recommended way of using the language).

Here are a few:

- [How to add hyperlink in iPhone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407492/how-to-add-hyperlink-in-iphone-app)
- [How to make a clickable link inside a NSTextField and Cocoa](http://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/358-how-to-make-a-clickable-link-inside-a-nstextfield-and-cocoa)
- [Text as Hyperlink in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610737/text-as-hyperlink-in-objective-c)

If I had a 3 `UILabel`s,

> Item 1
>
> Item 2
>
> Item 3

then what would be the best "Swift-y" way to make each item open to a different URL in Safari?

I could create separate buttons for each, but the `UILabel`s are programmatically populated, so I was thinking that making the text respond to taps might be a better option.

Comment: Having multiple URLs in a UILabel is a bit tricky in either language.  You will need to detect the tap in the label's rect and then try and work out which line was touched.  It would be much simpler using multiple UILabels as all you would need is a simple `touchUpInside` handler

Comment: @Paulw11 Alright: I'll try that. Would you mind writing an answer using that scenario? I'll change my question to reflect different structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The One approach would be something like the following.
The assumptions are:

- self.urls is a string array containing the urls associated with each `UILabel`.
- Each `UILabel` `tag` has been set to the corresponding index in the array
- `labelTapped:` is set as the `touchUpInside` handler for the labels.

```swift
import Foundation
import UIKit

class urltest {

    var urls:[String]

    init() {
        self.urls=[String]()  // Load URLs into here
    }

    @IBAction func labelTapped(sender:UILabel!) {

        let urlIndex=sender.tag;
        if (urlIndex >= 0 && urlIndex < self.urls.count) {
           self.openUrl(self.urls[urlIndex]);
        }

    }

    func openUrl(url:String!) {

        let targetURL=NSURL.URLWithString(url)

        let application=UIApplication.sharedApplication()

        application.openURL(targetURL);

    }
}
```

Comment: Looks to me like you have duplicated the function of a button.

Comment: Then I would have to ask, out of curiosity, why? A button is just a piece of text that calls an action when you tap it. That is exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: @TimQuinn The problem here was more opening Safari than it was calling the action: these are `UILabel`s and that is why I asked for a solution using them. I could use a button, but why change it if the only difference is adding a touchup handler to the label?

Comment: @TimQuinn I actually did end up making them buttons because the way they're handled natively is more suited to it than the way `UILabel`s are. I was hesitant to do so originally because my intent was to have something resembling a list, but the buttons were similar enough to the labels to work out.

Answer (score 7):

**Swift 3**
I created a LinkUILabel class in github:
https://github.com/jorgecsan/LinkUILabel
With this you only need add the url inspectable as the shows the image:
[image: Example label with url] or assign the url variable programmatically:

```
linkUILabel.url = "www.example.com"
```

If you want to implement by your self also I found that solution!:)

using:

```
// This is the label
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()

    // This is the key
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.onClicLabel(sender:)))
    label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    label.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

// And that's the function :)
func onClicLabel(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    openUrl("http://www.google.com")
}


func openUrl(urlString:String!) {
    let url = URL(string: urlString)!
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    } else {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!:)

Answer (score 1):

Hyperlink via UITextView

```
var termsConditionsTextView: UITextView = {
let view = UITextView()
 view.backgroundColor = .clear
 view.textAlignment = .left
 
 let firstTitleString = "By registering for THIS_APP I agree with the "
 let secondTitleString = "Terms & Conditions"
 let finishTitleString = firstTitleString + secondTitleString
 let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: finishTitleString)
 attributedString.addAttribute(.link, value: "https://stackoverflow.com", range: NSRange(location: firstTitleString.count, length: secondTitleString.count))
 
 view.attributedText = attributedString
 view.textContainerInset = .zero
 view.linkTextAttributes = [
     .foregroundColor: UIColor.blue,
     .underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.single.isEmpty
 ]
 
 view.font = view.font = UIFont(name: "YOUR_FONT_NAME", size: 16)
 view.textColor = UIColor.black
 
 return view }()
```