# Make button hyperlink Swift

Tags: swift

I am using swift and as it is a fairly new programing language there is not much documentation on it.
I am trying to make a button act as a hyperlink. I have created an IBAction but I do not know where to go from there. Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func WebLink(sender: AnyObject) {

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Comment: Check this post out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25477547/how-can-i-create-a-hyperlink-with-swift

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can open a URL by calling the `openURL` method on the UIApplication instance:

```
@IBAction func WebLink(sender: AnyObject) {
    if let url = NSURL(string: "http://...") {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For Swift 3 openURL has been deprecated.

Instead there is open which takes options and a completion handler:

sharedApplication() has also been replaced with the property shared.

```
if let url = URL(string: "https://...") {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:]) {
        boolean in
        // do something with the boolean
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The API is not available in versions lower than iOS 10, so the following needs to be added.

```
guard let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com/") else {
    return
}
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:]) {_ in }
} else {
    // Fallback on earlier versions
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
}
```