# iOS 8 linking to a website through a text view

Tags: swift, hyperlink, ios8, textview, nsdatadetector

I'm working on an app that needs to link to Stripe's terms of service website. I have a text view in my view controller. 
https://stripe.com/connect/account-terms works as a link when I set the behavior to Selectable and the detection to links and addresses.
However, I would link to hide the link behind the phrase "Stripe Connected Account Agreement".

Does anyone know how to do this using Swift and iOS 8?

Also, as a design choice, I do not have to do anything except have a link present to the terms of service to meet legal compliance. Still, should I consider implementing a web view?

Comment: Is it okay if the entire textview is clicked? I don't think you can make a link with custom text. If so, you can do something similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26938495/make-button-hyperlink-swift

Answer (score 0):

Use a NSAttributedString constructed like this: `NSAttributedString(string:"Stripe Connected Account Agreement", attributes:[NSLinkAttributeName: NSURL(string:"http://website.com")])`