# Adding Hyperlink to Swift Code dynamically

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to swift/ios development. I have a scenario where I am generating html string on the go and setting this to as the content of my UIWebView. But my content will contain href = "href_name". Once this href will be clicked I need change the content of same UIWebView. But this new content will not come from file, this will be set inside view controller which will be generated dynamically as well, based on which href is clicked. So, I also need to know how to grab which href_name is being currently clicked. So bottom line,

1. I need to know how to link href to an IBAction?
2. How to grab the name of current href?
3. Which method to run/override when I'll try to reset/reload the content of web view.

So far I can generate the html string and visualize this in UIWebView with with href tag in it. But this tag performs no action.

Please help, 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to know how to link href to an IBAction?

Take a look at 
[webView(_:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:). It should fire when a link is clicked. The request parameter should have the whole URL for you to read and you can open another controller from there. Please note that this is a delegate method, you need to implement the appropriate protocol etc.

> How to grab the name of current href?

If you use the method above, the URL should be accessible via the request parameter.

> Which method to run/override when I'll try to reset/reload the content of web view.

[reload()](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/reload)?

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
func openUrl(url:String!) {

        let targetURL=NSURL.URLWithString(url)

        let application=UIApplication.sharedApplication()

        application.openURL(targetURL);

    }
```

refer this [How can I create a "hyperlink" with Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25477547/how-can-i-create-a-hyperlink-with-swift)