# Swift - recognize a link and make it clickable

Tags: swift, hyperlink

I have an app that loads blog posts from a Wordpress site.
Now loading the text, images and video's work fine.

In the blog posts from Wordpress are links. Like for example: https://eenvandaag.avrotros.nl/item/ondanks-droogte-op-de-veluwe-onttrekt-kartonfabriek-parenco-er-jaarlijks-miljarden-liters-grondwater/

When the app loads the post, the link is displayed in plain text.

Is there a way to recognise the links and make these "links" clickable and guide the user to safari?
I've been searching the internet for hours but couldn't find a fitting solution.

Every post has a different link. So the goal is that the link is recognised and made clickable.

I found some examples, for example:

```
 var body: some View {
      VStack {
        Text(attributedString)
        Text("Check out [this link](https://stack.com)")
      }
    }

    var attributedString: AttributedString {
      var attributedText = AttributedString("Visit website")
      attributedText.link = URL(string: "https://stack.com")
      return attributedText
    }
```

But then you have to set the link.
So that doesn't work for me since the link is different for every post.
Can someone point me in the right direction?

This is the code for my PostContentView

```
import AVKit
import CachedAsyncImage
import SwiftUI
import WPArticleView

struct PostContentView: View {

   let post: Post

   var body: some View {

       VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 32) {
           if let url = post.embedded.medias?.first?.url {
               CachedAsyncImage(url: url, urlCache: .imageCache) { phase in
                   switch phase {
                   case.empty:
                       ProgressView()
                           .progressViewStyle(.circular)
                           .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)

                   case.success(let image):
                       image
                           .resizable()
                           .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                           .cornerRadius(8)
                           .frame(height: 200)
                           .padding(.bottom, 16)
                           .padding(.top, -10)

                   case.failure:
                       ZStack{
                           Image(systemName: "wifi.slash")
                               .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.white))
                           RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 6)
                               .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemGray5))
                               .frame(height: 200)
                               .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                       }

                   @unknown default:
                       EmptyView()
                   }
               }
           }

           VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 16) {
               Text(post.title.text)
                   .font(.title2).bold()
                   .padding(.horizontal)
                   .foregroundColor(.white)

               Text(post.date.formattedDateString)
                   .font(.footnote)
                   .padding(.horizontal)
                   .foregroundColor(.white)

               WPArticleView(htmlBody: post.content.rendered) { blocks in

                   ForEach(blocks.indices, id: \.self) { id in
                       blocks[id]
                           .padding(.bottom, 6)
                           .padding(.horizontal)
                           .foregroundColor(.white)
                           .textSelection(.enabled)
                   }

               } text: { attributedText in

                   Text(attributedText)

               } image: { imageURL in

                   CachedAsyncImage(url: imageURL, urlCache: .imageCache) { image in
                       image
                           .resizable()
                           .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                           .cornerRadius(8)
                   } placeholder: {
                       //EmptyView()
                       ProgressView()
                           .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                   }

               } video: { videoURL in

                   VideoPlayer(player: AVPlayer(url: videoURL))
                       .frame(minHeight: 250)
                       //.frame(minHeight: 400)
                       .cornerRadius(8)

               }
           }
       }
       .padding(.horizontal, 20)
   }

}
```

And my Post screen:

```
import Foundation

struct Post: Decodable, Identifiable {

   let id: Int

   let date: Date
   let title: Title
   let content: Content
   let embedded: Embedded

   enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
       case date = "date"
       case title = "title"
       case content = "content"
       case embedded = "_embedded"
       case id = "id"
   }

}
```

EDIT:
Here is an example from a post:
[image]

Comment: It's unclear. In `Post`, there might a link? How? Where? Is it HTML? Markdown? Could you provide an example?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I edited the question with an example image.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create a "hyperlink" with Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25477547/how-can-i-create-a-hyperlink-with-swift)

Comment: Your like is as such, "raw" inside the text?

Comment: You have 2 choices really: 1 - Display HTML as is, using WKWebView or Safari.  2 - Parse the HTML and retrieve / build links. Basically you will be doing a conversion from HTML to MD (markdown) format, which `Text` element would understand. You can lookup for existing Swift HTML->MD conversion library, that will make things easier.

Comment: I wanted to let you know that i made it working with WKWebView. Thank you again for your advise!